# Work with laravel tinker

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel .

I want to work with php artisan tinker in cygwin but I am getting some errors in making an object. I watched some videos and the guy did this:

```
$article = new app\articles;
```

but when I do this it says:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'app\articles' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

I tried this too:

```
$article = new c://xampp/htdocs/laravel/app/articles;
```

but it says this:

```
PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected ':' on line 1
```

Comment: try `App\Articles`, namespace is case sensitive.

Answer (score 11):

Tinker is case sensitive so if you are trying to create the object the way you are doing it it will fail so instead try placing the whole namespace in the exact way it is on your project

`$article = new App\Article;`

Comment: just a quick note, `Thinker` should be `Tinker`

Answer (score 3):

Use terminal to go to your project, and type :

```
php artisan tinker
```

Then type the following command for example to create a new `Article`:

```
$article = new Article;
```

After that you can manipulate the article like any `Article` object :

```
$article->title = "foo";
```

Maybe you should take a look at **Laravel Fundamentals** at [laracasts.com](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/), it's a greate serie for Laravel beginners.

Regards.